# Can I Ignore PHP Version Requirements for Pear Package Install

Tags: php, pear

I'm trying to install a couple of pear packages but have an issue with the version of PHP I'm running. Firstly I get:

```
sudo pear install phix/Autoloader
Failed to download phix/Autoloader, latest release is version 3.0.0, but it requires PHP version "5.3.0", use "channel://pear.phix-project.org/Autoloader-3.0.0" to install
Cannot initialize 'channel://pear.phix-project.org/Autoloader', invalid or missing package file
Package "channel://pear.phix-project.org/Autoloader" is not valid
install failed
```

I then try and install as follows:

```
sudo pear install channel://pear.phix-project.org/Autoloader-3.0.0
phix/Autoloader requires PHP (version >= 5.3.0), installed version is 5.2.6-1+lenny13
No valid packages found
install failed
```

Would I be correct in assuming the error is related to the version of PHP I'm running? If so, is there a way of getting the pear install to ignore the PHP version requirements?

Thanks

Comment: Ignoring those will probably not help you as the code is using language features that are not available below PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: The error message is explaining that 5.3.0 is a requirement. Ignoring it is like trying to put diesel in a petrol engine, it won't work!

Comment: I realised it was a requirement, but wanted to see if I could force it anyway - I didn't think it was very likely. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you bring PEAR to ignore the version, you cannot use the packages, because the *requirements* are not fulfilled. There are really good reasons, why the package maintainers set the requirements.
Thus: No, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look into

```
pear help install
```

This should list you all available options. As written in my comment above, I don't think it makes sense, but you can just try harder to make pear installing the package anyway. The package then might just not work in the end, but well, that are "just" requirements you'd like to ignore anyway, so go ahead ;)